# Rewrite Rule on apache2 with tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, apache2, url-rewriting, mod-jk

I am trying to rewrite a request from a GWT-Webapplication, to be more specific: gwtupload. The Webapplication is bound to apache2 via mod_jk.

I need to rewrite the following request:

```
    http://www.example.com/servlet.gupld?new_session=true&random=0.3840860207955523
```

To

```
    http://www.example.com/webapp/servlet.gupld?new_session=true&random=0.3840860207955523
```

Anything after servlet.gupld? has to be variable.

The Webapp itself works fine and is boud like this:

```
    <IfModule mod_jk.c>
    JkMount /webapp/* tomcat3
    JkLogLevel error
    </IfModule>
```

While my (not working) rewrite rule looks like this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/www.example.com/www>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase   /
    RewriteRule   ^/servlet\.gupld /webapp/servlet\.gupld [PT,L]
    </Directory>
```

For the moment I am always getting a 404 on the request to the servlet.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape the "." in the rewrite. You only need `/webapp/servlet.gupld`

You'll also want `QSA` flag in the rewrite rule so that query strings get passed.

Comment: I just changed it to
        `RewriteRule servlet.gupld /falschparker/falschparker/servlet.gupld [PT,QSA]`
But somehow the Query string isn't passed to the servlet. Any ideas?

Comment: That rule will loop. Try `RewriteRule ^servlet.gupld(.*)$ /falschparker/falschparker/servlet.gupld$1 [PT,QSA,L]` if that doesn't work try adding a / right after the ^